# Is there a general way to compute fixed fields by using other (already computed) fixed fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, abelian-groups

I know this question is a little vague, so I try to formulate the problem a bit more precisely.

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension and $G$ the corresponding Galois group. We also suppose that $G$ is abelian.

Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 \in G$, and $L_i = L^{\langle \sigma_i \rangle}$ for $i=1,2$. With the primtive element theorem, the extensions $L_1/K$ and $L_2/K$ are both simple, i.e. $L_i = K(\alpha_i)$ for certain $\alpha_i \in L_i$.

Let $L' = L^{\langle \sigma_1\sigma_2 \rangle}$.

> **Question**: Is it possible to find a generator of $L'/K$ (i.e. an element $\beta \in L'$ with $L' = K(\beta)$) using $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?

This question is interesting for me because I have to compute lots of fixed fields for my work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you know the naive/natural method for finding $L'=\sum_{j=1}^J b_j K$ when a $K$-basis and the Galois action on $L$ is known? A primitive element $a = \sum_{j=1}^J c_j b_j$ can be found by trying enough $c_j\in K$, counting the number of conjugates of $a$.

Comment: By the naive method, you mean basically finding an appropriate eigenvector of eigenvalue $1$? I think I am familiar with that. I don't understand the argument with counting the numbers of cunjugates though.

Comment: No idea what you mean. The point is that $Tr_{L/L'}$ is surjective $L\to L'$, so from a $K$-basis of $L$ we'll have a $K$-basis of $L'$

Comment: What kind of map is $Tr_{L/L'} $? I don't understand it.